# Comparing Time Values To Find New Records Taking Forever

Tags: php

Okay. So I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my script is taking forever to run. I've pinpointed a potential cause and would like to figure out a more efficient way of performing this following functionality:

```
function getwrs($obj, $recs) {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($recs); $i++) {
            $wr = array();
            if ($recs[$i][0] === $key) {
                $wr = $recs[$i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count($wr) > 0) {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($val); $i++) {
                if ($val[$i]["time"] < $wr[1] && abs($wr[1] - $val[$i]["time"]) < 30) {
                    $uwrs[] = array($val[$i], $wr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $uwrs;
}
```

I'm calling this function like so:

```
$wrs = getwrs($top15["pro"], $recs);
```

where `$top15["pro"]` is a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
[MAP1NAME] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [authid] => XXXX
        [name] => XXXX
        [time] => XXXX
        [date] => XXXX
        ...
    )
)
[MAP2NAME] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [authid] => XXXX
        [name] => XXXX
        [time] => XXXX
        [date] => XXXX
        ...
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [authid] => XXXX
        [name] => XXXX
        [time] => XXXX
        [date] => XXXX
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```

and contains just over 1500 entries, and $recs is an array containing comparable values and about 3000 entries with the following structure:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => MAP1NAME
        [1] => TIMEVAL
        [2] => USERNAME1
        [3] => COUNTRY
    )
    ...
```

The purpose of this function is to find unofficial world records by comparing time values for each map in my database (`$top15`) with time values from an official world records array (`$recs`).

Right now I take each map name from my database and find the same string from the official world records array, then store the official world record values for the map in a variable `$wr` if there is an official record. Next I loop through the array of completed times from my database to find which ones, if any, are less than the official record time. Each time this is true I push both the info pertaining to my database time and the official record time (user, time, etc.) to a new array. This is repeated for every key (map name) from my database. Finally, the function returns my unofficial world records array (`$uwrs`).

The problem is simply: this takes too damned long for some reason. I originally coded my script in JavaScript and it was quite responsive, so I'm maybe thinking I'm doing something wrong here. Any help?

Edit: I've used xdebug to pinpoint the problem and when I add the call to this function my output file goes from 3MB to over 30MB and the script run time goes from about 1 second to 15-20s. I'm relatively new to this tool so I don't know if this information is important or not.

Edit 2: as per request the structure of my database is as follows:

```
map | authid | name | time | date | weapon
```

ex:

```
kzbr_brickngrasshop | STEAM_0:1:XXXXXXX | John Travolta kz-endo | 23.582824 | 2013-08-25 | 03:40:17 | knife
```

Comment: Can you provide any idea about your database tables? Once I had to solve very similar to yours wheres initially i was fetching all the records from my DB and searching for a key in them and again querying my DB based on those results. This was a pretty slow job when the db grow bigger. Then I used some advanced mysql queries to get what I wanted all at a time. I assume you should do the same- use database queries to fetch you data.

Comment: The thing is that I need all of the rows from my database for other functionality. For example, I have also made a points system that requires every entry from the database. Regardless, fetching and storing the rows alone takes only about 600ms. It is only when I'm iterating through them that I get this huge slow down, so I know the issue lies within my PHP script rather than my SQL queries.

Comment: You were running two loops inside another loop that made your script to slow down. Thanks to the performance of your server and PHP itself that your script didn't actually stopped working. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading your problem several times I'm assuming that your require a way to compare data from two different tables.

For demonstration purpose and simplicity, assume that you have two table `official` and `unofficial`.

`official` and `unofficial` tables share the same structure which is-

```
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
    mapid   |    authid   |   name   |   time   |   date
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
  map1name  |    1        |   bob    | 03:40:17 | 2013-08-25
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
  map2name  |    2        |   hop    | 01:10:56 | 2012-04-12
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
  map3name  |    3        | cherry   | 11:08:14 | 2013-05-14
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
  map4name  |    4        |   adam   | 09:16:43 | 2013-07-10
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
  map5name  |    5        |   zyl    | 06:01:53 | 2012-09-30
------------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------
```

Now what you can do is perform some advanced mysqlqueries to find data from both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM `unofficial` JOIN `official` WHERE `official.mapid` = `unofficial.mapid` AND TIME_TO_SEC(`official.time`) > TIME_TO_SEC(`unofficial.time`) AND  ABS( TIME_TO_SEC(`official.time`) - TIME_TO_SEC(`unofficial.time`) ) < 1800
```

WHAT IS DONE HERE:

Here we have performed a mysql query joining both table and fetching results after performing three conditions-

(i) their map ids have to be same. From your codes above I think you want to match the map ids from both tables in order to find the unofficial world records.

(ii) time from `unofficial` table has to be less than the time of the `official` table. Again I'm assuming it from your code above. `TIME_TO_SEC` is a `mysql` function which converts time to seconds. Like TIME_TO_SEC('01:01:06') returns 3666.

(iii) And the third is the difference between the time is lower than 30 seconds. Again its in your code.

My query might have some errors like spelling mistake or selecting wrong columns etc as i didn't test it against a real database. But the idea is pretty much same. You can search for the appropriate query or read the documentation.

I hope that will help you.

Comment: good to point out the existence of sql for this problem.  You are, however, converting the mapids to seconds :)

Comment: Right now I am using a task/cronjob to parse a .txt file once per day (to keep the official records up-to-date) and store it in json format in a file on my server. My PHP is currently reading from this json file when I run my script. Would it be beneficial to store the official world records in another table in my database so I could test your method using pure SQL?

Comment: it should. Databases are designed to store and retrieve data and they can do it immense powerfully. you should directly update the database table for your official records. You can use a php script to parse the json file and update it to the database and again in reverse return data from the database in json object. In that way you can just use php to deliver your data and use sql to fetch your data based on any condition you like. I think its more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating 13,000,000 different variables and setting them to the length of each array BEFORE performing the loop. Reading up revealed that I was counting to 1500/3000/etc. each time I used a for loop. Guess it affects performance in PHP..